# Switch to table view and collection view using jquery

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

In same page I have to give table and a collection view based on user's choice. For table im using jquery datatables plugin. To collection view I'm using ajax function to get html data from the server. 
What is the best way to create this switching part without loading whole thing, but load data based on user's choice.

These are the buttons i use for switch

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <a href="#" id="list" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-th-list'></i> Table</a>
    <a href="#" id="grid" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-th'></i> Grid</a>
</div>
```

Datatable generate

```
<div class="box-body table-responsive">
    <?php
    echo $this->table->generate();
    ?>
</div>

 var oTable = $('#big_table').dataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bPaginate": true,
    "bLengthChange": true,
    "bFilter": true,
    "bSort": true,
    "bInfo": true,
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": '<?php echo base_url(); ?>products/datatable',
    "bJQueryUI": false,
    "iDisplayStart ": 20,
    "oLanguage": {
        "sProcessing": "<img src='<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/ajax-loader_dark.GIF' style='margin-left:20px;'>"
    },
    "fnInitComplete": function () {
        //oTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing();
    },
    'fnServerData': function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
        $.ajax
        ({
            'dataType': 'json',
            'type': 'POST',
            'url': sSource,
            'data': aoData,
            'success': fnCallback
        });
    }
});
```

Collection View Generate

```
<div id="pageData"></div>

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url('paginate/pagination'); ?>",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(result){
        //closeModal();
        $("#pageData").html(result);
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: can u make it fiddle? or can you clarify you are looking for to change alignment while clicking on table should content comes in table. while click on grid, the contents should comes in grid?

Comment: @punithasubramaniv Its impossible to create exact scenario in fiddle. What I want is when i click grid I want to display collection view which i'm getting throug ajax. And when I click list I want to render table in to div and hide collection view.

Comment: Then shall I work out this with sample datas created by my own

Comment: please look above picture I added. Currently I render both views to same page. But I want one at a time.If you can explain better way to do this it will be really helpful

Comment: Can someone please suggest a method to do this. At least steps?

Comment: I will prepare some sample for you, am working out it

Comment: really appreciate friend

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60669/discussion-between-dushan-and-punitha-subramani-v).

Answer (score 1):

Somthing like this , Can you try it? I just did it on CSS with same values

TEST.PHP

SCRIPT

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function () {
        $('button').click(function(){
            var idButton=$(this).attr('id');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "test.php",
                data: "layout="+idButton,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {    
                    $('body').html(html);
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

HTML

```
    <div>
      <button id="1">TABLE</button>
      <button id="2">GRID</button>
    </div>
```

PHP

```
    <?php if(isset($_POST['layout'])) {
    if($_POST['layout']=="1"){ ?>
    <style>
        .display-view
        {
            display:table;
            width:100%;
        }
        .display-row,
        {
            display:table-row;
        }
        .display-row > div
        {
            display: table-cell;
            border:1px solid #000;
        }
        .display-name 
        {
            text-align:right;
        }
        .display-type,.display-name{
            width:50px;
        }
    </style>
    <?php }  else { ?>
    <style>
       .display-view{
            border:1px solid #f00;
            border-radius:2px;
            box-shadow:2px 2px 2px #fff;
            display:block;
            height:500px;
            padding:50px;

       }
       .display-row{
         float:left;
         margin-left:10px;
       }
       .display-type{
        background-color:#ccc;
        color:#fff;
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
       }
    </style>
    <?php } ?>
        <div class="display-view">
            <div class="display-row">
                <div class="display-type">Product 1</div>
                <div class="display-name">Product 2 </div>                
            </div>
            <div class="display-row">
                <div class="display-type">value 1</div>
                <div class="display-name">value 2</div>                
            </div>      
            <div class="display-row">
                <div class="display-type">value 11</div>
                <div class="display-name">value 12</div>                
            </div>  
            <div class="display-row">
                <div class="display-type">value 21</div>
                <div class="display-name">value 22</div>                
            </div>              
        </div>
    <?php  }  ?>
```